# Is it possible to reference random classes?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

Is there a way to get user input to reference random class instances? I mean based on the ones that have been created? Kind of like a switch, but without writing out every instance inside the switch? I want my code to be more universal so that others can add to it without changing a switch or other parts of the code.

I know the organization of the post is kind of zig-zaggy but I felt it's the best way to organize my thoughts on a post so please bear with me. In the code at the very bottom I make a pointer to change variables in the "test1" instance. I would like to be able to make a way that the program would be able to get user input to pick which class and then change it there. I know this syntax doesn't work but for example:

```
class test {
public:
    int number;
    int letter;
}
test classTest; //to get user input of which class he wants to select
                //to change a variable
cin >> classTest; //user inputs choice
test * classPointer; //pointer to variables
cin >> classPointer -> number;
cin >> classPointer -> letter;
//where classTest is actually not a normal instance, just a way to get user
//input to select which class instance variables he'd like to change
```

Here is a little background of where my problem begins and this question stems from. You can skip it if you don't care about it/need it to answer me. I'm writing a RPG game to practice what I've been learning in C++ and I want to make the code I write fairly universal. For example, if I have a class that creates certain objects that are universal in "towns." Like an item shop, an inn, etc. In the battle system you can choose to use an item. In that item category though should only be listed items that are available. That's no problem, I can write a ton of if's and switches and booleans--however I don't want to write all of that for each item in the battle system I would like some kind of mechanism that would do that for me. I believe that some trick with how pointers can be called will be the remedy to my problem here. However, all this being said please don't get sidetracked by my background story. It is only meant to aide you in seeing my thought process and if it won't solve this problem so be it, I need to know this information for pointers anyways.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class test {
public:
    int number;
    char letter;
    void function() {
        printf("Number = %d\nLetter = %c", number, letter);
    }
    test() {}
    test(int a, char b) : number(a), letter(b) {}
};

int main()
{
    test* pointer;
    test test1(1, 'c');
    pointer = &test1;
    test1.function(); //output initial result
    printf("\nEnter a new number: ");
    std::cin >> pointer -> number; //change number
    printf("Enter a new letter: ");
    std::cin >> pointer -> letter; //change letter
    test1.function(); //output changed result
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to create a lookup table of some kind that maps strings to classes somehow. If you can use the C++11 lambda feature, you can probably do this in a fairly clean way, as otherwise you need function pointers.

Comment: I'm completely perplexed why you'd have `test* pointer` and `test test1` as basically the same thing. If you need a pointer, use the `new` allocator, otherwise use a stack-based instance. It doesn't make much sense to use both.

Comment: @tadman This is how I learned to use pointers. I didn't realize that the instance test1 was almost the same thing as a pointer in this program. Could you elaborate how you mean? I wrote the pointer = &test1 just as an example if that means anything. What I really want is instead of &test1 be &userInput.

Comment: Sounds like basic polymorphism. Do the classes need to be extensible at runtime, like an application plugin? If so, you need a factory pattern that creates objects compatible with a provided base type. If not, well, you can still use the same pattern but it becomes easier. Even if I only have two types, I still prefer polymorphic behavior through a base class pointer or reference over a conditional. Let the vtable be your switch statement.

Comment: Normally you have something like `test* p = new test(...)` or `test s(...)` where you want a pointer explicitly, you're intending to use it outside of the local scope, or you don't care and a stack-allocated object is fine. Calling `p->fn()` is the same as `s.fn()`. To learn C++ effectively, you'll need to know when you need a pointer, and how to assign "ownership" of this allocation, when you can use a container class that "owns" it, and when to use a stack-allocated local. Mix pointers, references and locals for different variables, but be consistent with your approach for any one thing.

Comment: Ah, I think I get what you're saying. Normally I would be calling it by the instance name instead of creating a pointer and then going indirectly--but I figured this was the best way to explain my situation. I want whatever class they enter into the "cin" to be the class the pointer is pointing to. But I've been told it's not possible how it is and that I need to do other things like maps and factory patterns--which I'm having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little mystified by the code snippets and the dense text, but the sort of problem you describe is a fairly common one.

To create objects of a type based on some key you would want to look at an abstract factory pattern as your starting point - available in all good text books and more reputable wikis near you. Don't be put off if it looks overblown for your purposes - as with all patterns you can cut it down to suit your needs.

In essence, for each type of object you want to create, you need a factory that knows how to make it. All the factories required to make this collection of related objects should share the same interface.

To pick the right factory to create a requested class of object you hold a map of keys, i.e. strings to factories. The map replaces the if-else/switches you may have been tempted to use. If you want to minimize typing and confound your enemies and friends alike, a Singleton can be used to to register factories against keys, but please read all the health warnings first:

```
// Base class for alldwellings in your town
class Dwelling
{
public:
   virtual ~Dwelling() {}
   virtual Dwelling(int number, char letter);
   virtual Enter() = 0;
   virtual Leave() = 0;
   // ... Whatever other common things you can do in a town dwelling */ 
};

// A type of dwelling - as many of these as you like
class Shop : public Dwelling
{
   virtual Shop(int number, char letter)
     : Dwelling (number, letter)
   { /* stuff */}
   virtual Enter();
   virtual Leave();
};

// Base factory class for making a type of dwelling
class AbstractDwellingFactory
{
public:
   virtual DwellingFactory() {}
   virtual Dwelling * Create(int number, char letter) = 0;
};

// Collection and registrar of all dwelling factories - a Meyer's Singleton for convenience
class DwellingFactory
{
public:
   static DwellingFactory & Instance()
   {
       static DwellingFactory theInstance;
       return theInstance;
   }
   // Create a dwelling from the given type and other parameters - consider smart pointers rather than the raw pointer shown here
   Dwelling * Create(std::string const & dwelling dwellingType, int number, char letter)
   {
      // Assuming we have a matching factory, make us a dwelling.
      // Obviously some error checking is required here in the real world 
      return myAbstractDwellingFactoryMap[dwellingType].Create(number, letter);
   }
   void Register(std::strinf const & dwellingType, AbstractDwellingFactory const & fact)
   {
      myAbstractDwellingFactory[dwellingType] = &fact;
   }
private:
   DwellingFactory() {}
   // The actual key to type mapping
   std::map myAbstractDwellingFactoryMap;
};

// A generic concrete factory
template <typename DwellingType>
class ConcreteDwellingFactory : public AbstractDwellingFactory
{
public:
   ConcreteDwellingFactory(std::string const & dwellingType)
   {
      DwellingFactory::Instance().Register(dwellingType, *this);
   }
   // Factory function - note we can return a pointer to a derived type here - look up 'co variant return types'
   DwellingType * Create(int number, char letter)
   {
      return new DwellingType;
   }

};

// A factory instance for each dwelling type you want to support
static ConcreteDwellingFactory<Shop> shopFactory("Shop");

void SomeFunction()
{
   std::string dwellingType;
   int number;
   char letter;

   std::cin >> dwellingType >> number >> letter;
   Dwelling *requestedDwelling(DwellingFactory::Instance().Create(dwellingType, number, letter));
   requestedDwelling->Enter(); // et cetera
}
```

Comment: Right now my towns are actually instances of classes. Like... town Frosttown(1,0,1) //has an inn, no shop, has a person to talk to.. When I move to certain positions on the world map it calls <townname>.options(); //<townname> being actual towns typed out. The options function looks through the parameters set in the constructor and several other variables including global variables to piece together what to do in the town instance. From your post it looks like I want to avoid that and make towns inherited classes of the base class town? And same with items classes, etc?

Comment: Yes, if there are different types of towns, they can share the same base and implement options() as required. If a town is defined purely by the items (or dwellings) it contains then it could be a simple class containing a set of items determined on construction. The process of building that particular town from a set of items can be offloaded into a separate factory. It sounds like you could probably use a table of some sort to describe what the various towns contain instead of coding up individual classes for each variation.

Comment: A table like what was mentioned in the comments to my question? Or is there something in Boost or the STL?

Comment: @Scott mentioned in the comments above is 'a lookup table of some kind that maps strings to classes somehow'. This is achievable using the boost::fusion library for a limited number of classes or there are ways of hand-rolling it for an arbitrary number of classes. This wasn't what I was suggesting

Comment: What I was getting at is that  your towns can be built from a number of objects of a finite number of classes constructed according to a recipe held in a table (or set of linked tables.) Such tables could be simple arrays of structs, containers made from initializer lists (C++11) or read from XML files or a even a database.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't accept your answer right away--probably because I was a little confused at the time but I understand it now. And yes, my code is confusing me too after looking at it several months later. Thanks for your help, answer accepted.